# React contexts with array hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'am having problem with this contexts.

At

```
<RubroContext.Provider  value={ {rubro,setRubro} } >
```

I got this errer message:

```
The type '{ rubro: itemRybri[]; setRubro:
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<itemRubro[]>>; }' cannot be
assigned to type 'Partial<RubroType>'.
 
The object literal can only specify known properties, but "rubro" does
not exist in type "Partial<RubroType>"
```

interface:

```
  export interface itemRubro {
    rubro:string
    radius:string
    description:string
    calificacion:number
    pais:string
    provincia:string
    ciudad:string
    calle:string
    numeracion:string
    days_of_works:string
    hour_init:string
    hour_end:string
    certificate:string
    picture1:string
    picture2:string
    picture3:string

  }

  export type RubroType = {
    rubros: itemRubro [];
    setRubro: Dispatch<SetStateAction<itemRubro []>>;
  }
```

This is the context definition:

```
export const  RubroContext = createContext <Partial<RubroType>>({});

export const useUserContext = () => useContext(RubroContext);
```

The app.tsx

```
const App: React.FC = () => {

 const [rubro,setRubro] = useState <itemRubro[]> ([])

 useEffect(() => {

getItem("infoRubro1").then(res2 => {
          setRubro1(res2)
          setRubro([...rubro, {
            rubro:res2.rubro,
            radius:res2.radius,
            description:res2.description,
            calificacion:res2.calificacion,
            pais:res2.pais,
            provincia:res2.provincia,
            ciudad:res2.ciudad,
            calle:res2.calle,
            numeracion:res2.numeracion,
            days_of_works:res2.days_of_works,
            hour_init:res2.hour_init,
            hour_end:res2.hour_end,
            certificate:res2.certificate,
            picture1:res2.picture1,
            picture2:res2.picture2,
            picture3:res2.picture3,
            }])
        })
        getItem("infoRubro2").then(res2 => {
          setRubro2(res2)
          setRubro([...rubro, {
            rubro:res2.rubro,
            radius:res2.radius,
            description:res2.description,
            calificacion:res2.calificacion,
            pais:res2.pais,
            provincia:res2.provincia,
            ciudad:res2.ciudad,
            calle:res2.calle,
            numeracion:res2.numeracion,
            days_of_works:res2.days_of_works,
            hour_init:res2.hour_init,
            hour_end:res2.hour_end,
            certificate:res2.certificate,
            picture1:res2.picture1,
            picture2:res2.picture2,
            picture3:res2.picture3,
            }])
        })
}, []);


    <RubroContext.Provider  value={ {rubro,setRubro} } >
       <SomeOtherComponets >
    </RubroContext.Provider >
```

Answer (score 1):

With context and TypeScript, using Partial for the context type will throw your downstream types off. If you're doing that just because you must pass *something* to `createContext`, I'd recommend passing an empty object and *asserting* that it's of the proper type.

```
export const RubroContext = createContext({} as RubroType);
```

This way, consumers of RubroContext will assume that it contains all the properties they're expecting - and it's still type-safe as long as you provide the context in a parent component - that is, with

```
<RubroContext.Provider  value={ {rubro,setRubro} } >
```

The type assertion only wouldn't be safe if it the context was being consumed without being provided, which is pretty unusual, at least in my experience. (If you're in a situation where the context *will* sometimes be used without being provided, then you should change the `createContext` call to provide all the needed information at that point - which, granted, is difficult at the top level in React)